# Selecting XML node values from multiple XMLs

Tags: sql, xml, join, nodes

I have a table with several rows. Each row holds an XML typed field 'descriptor'. A descriptor looks as:

```
<root>
  <item name="a" />
  <item name="b" />
</root>
```

In 'root' there can be several (0-100) 'item' node.

I want to select all the items' name from all table rows' descriptor at the same time (somehow like this):

```
create table #mytable (descriptor xml)
insert into #mytable (descriptor) values ('<root><item name="a"/><item name="b"/></root>')
insert into #mytable (descriptor) values ('<root><item name="c"/></root>')

SELECT p.value('./@name', 'nvarchar(100)')
 FROM M.descriptor.nodes('/root/item') as p(p)
 INNER JOIN #mytable M on 1=1
 OPTION ( OPTIMIZE FOR ( M.descriptor = NULL ) )
```

But it does not work :( My lack of knowledge with .nodes() and other sql specific things (sorry)... Does it possible anyway? What is the right syntax? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please tag your DBMS. Each maintain different if any XML extensions.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64). Quite old, but we live her :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted to use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
create table #mytable (descriptor xml)
insert into #mytable (descriptor) values ('<root><item name="a"/><item name="b"/></root>')
insert into #mytable (descriptor) values ('<root><item name="c"/></root>')

SELECT p.value('./@name', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM #mytable M
CROSS APPLY M.descriptor.nodes('/root/item') as p(p);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f2eae4fdd46a747ddefce345929c268b)**

Comment: I probably wanted :) but never heard about it :) Thanks a lot!